# Excel VBA Replace not executing

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which I am trying to use to replace text on a sheet with "". When I run the code, I don't receive an error but nothing changes, so it must be running on the backend but without the proper instruction. Any ideas for why that might be?

```
Sub Replacetext

Dim sd As Worksheet

    Set sd = Sheets("StatementData")

Dim sdlastrowv As Long

    sdlastrowv = sd.Cells(sd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim sdalldata As Range, sdcel As Range, sdcelv As String

Set sdalldata = sd.Range("A1", "K" & sdlastrowv)

sd.Activate

    For Each sdcel In sdalldata
        If InStr(1, sdcelv, "Investor Ref :") Then
            sdcel.Value.Replace What:="Investor Ref :", Replacement:=""
        End If
    Next sdcel

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd go for replace instead of going cell by cell `Set sdalldata = sd.Range("A1", "K" & sdlastrowv)` then `sdalldata.Replace "Investor Ref :", ""`. Note: if there are extra white spaces it won't replace it, are you sure this `"Investor Ref :"`  isn't a typo and should be `"Investor Ref:"`  instead?

Comment: This **will** raise an error if the value exists in the cell. You're not getting the error probably because of extra whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Code should be:

```
Sub Replacetext()

    Dim sd As Worksheet
    Set sd = Sheets("StatementData")

    Dim sdlastrowv As Long
    sdlastrowv = sd.Cells(sd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim sdalldata As Range, sdcel As Range, sdcelv As String
    Set sdalldata = sd.Range("A1", "K" & sdlastrowv)

    sd.Activate

    For Each sdcel In sdalldata
        If InStr(1, sdcel, "Investor Ref :") Then
            sdcel.Replace What:="Investor Ref :", Replacement:=""
        End If
    Next sdcel

End Sub
```

Changed `sdcelv` to `sdcel` and `sdcel.Value.Replace ...` to `sdcel.Replace ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working sub with some minor changes (look at the comments). I tried to stick to your original code as much as possible so you can find yourself in it. Furthermore, I implemented some good coding practices such as naming of variables and using `.Value2` instead of `.Value`:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub ReplaceTextCellByCell()

Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim rngAllData As Range, rngCell As Range

Set shtData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StatementData")
lngLastRow = shtData.Cells(shtData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'I exchanged the comma for a colon. The comma would mean
'  that you are referring to two cells only. The cell
'  A1 and the cell K20 (or whatever the last row is)
'  The colon instead means that you want every cell
'  between these two to be included in the range
Set rngAllData = shtData.Range("A1:K" & lngLastRow)

'The following line is not necessary. Therefore I commented it out.
'shtData.Activate

For Each rngCell In rngAllData
    If InStr(1, rngCell.Value2, "Investor Ref :") Then
        rngCell.Value = Replace(rngCell.Value2, "Investor Ref :", "")
    End If
Next rngCell

End Sub
```

The following sub is a slight improvement over the first sub in terms of speed. Furthermore, the last row is now no longer determined based on column `A` only but instead on the last overall row. You can change this back again if you prefer.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub ReplaceTextWithFind()

Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim rngAllData As Range, rngCell As Range, strFirstAddress As String

Set shtData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StatementData")
lngLastRow = shtData.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set rngAllData = shtData.Range("A1:K" & lngLastRow)

'Based on the example provided by Microsoft here
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

With rngAllData
    Set rngCell = .Find(What:="Investor Ref :", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not rngCell Is Nothing Then
        strFirstAddress = rngCell.Address
        Do
            rngCell.Value2 = Replace(rngCell.Value2, "Investor Ref :", "")
            Set rngCell = .FindNext(rngCell)
            If rngCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            If rngCell.Address = strFirstAddress Then Exit Sub
        Loop
    End If
End With

End Sub
```